# Implication in the space $W^{1,p}_0$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

If we have $$(f-g)\in W^{1,p}_0(E)$$

where $f,g$ are both positive, $p\geq 1$ and $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain, how do we then proof that also

$$\left(f^\alpha - g^\alpha\right) \in W^{1,\frac{p}{\alpha}}_0(E)$$

for arbitrary $p\geq \alpha \geq 1$? Intuitively this should be true because of
"$f=g$" on the boundary so also "$f^\alpha = g^\alpha$" but of course this is not yet a proof.

Comment: Do we have any condition on $E$ ? (like smoothness/boundedness)

Comment: Yes sorry, in general let's first just assume boundedness. I corrected it.

Comment: Isn't in general that if $f\in L^p$ then $f^\alpha \in L^{p/\alpha}$?

Comment: Oh yes of course, I corrected this as well, thanks. The thing I am interested in is the boundary condition...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ there is a sequence of $\varphi_n \in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ so that $ \varphi_n \to f-g$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Hence

$$ \varphi_n + g \to f$$
in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and

$$ (\varphi_n + g)^\alpha - g^\alpha \to f^\alpha - g^\alpha$$

in $W^{1,p/\alpha}(\Omega)$. Since $(\varphi_n+g)^\alpha - g^\alpha$ has compact support (indeed, the support is inside that of $\varphi_n$), we have $(\varphi_n+g)^\alpha - g^\alpha \in W^{1,p/\alpha}_0(\Omega)$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091376/if-u-in-w1-p-omega-has-support-compactly-inside-omega-then-u-in-w1)). Since $W^{1,p/\alpha}_0(\Omega)$ is by definition a closed subspace of $W^{1,p/\alpha}(\Omega)$ we conclude that $f^\alpha - g^\alpha \in W^{1,p/\alpha}_0(\Omega)$.

Comment: I'd add that the convergence in $W^{1,p/\alpha}(\Omega)$ is not immediate, and is a good exercise for the OP to verify. In particular it's crucial that we assume $\alpha \geq 1$ in this step, as the result can fail when $\alpha < 1$.